# Treating second debugging launch different from the first one?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010 (C# .NET 4.0), I am testing a client/server solution these days. It's a game that is quite heavy and laggy to run for both my CPU and GPU. It takes minutes to just get a connection going, and it's bothering me quite a lot. Also, the 2 games start on the same screen which is annoying, since I have a dual-monitor setup, which could easily be used to optimize the process.

How can I make a program do something different the 2nd time it starts up through Visual Studio 2010?

I realize I could do some compilation conditions or maybe use some Process hacks to see if an existing process is running, but I find that a bit unpure.

Any other ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve or what your problem is.

Comment: I think the whole idea of getting the program to do something different the 2nd time is quite unpure.

Comment: Your first paragraph doesn't seem relevant to your actual question, or the rest of your post. It's probably worth editing this one and posting other questions about the different aspects.

Comment: Is the debugging part relevant? Why not simply check if there is already an open instance of the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two copies of sources and open them in two instances of VS. You'll be able to debug both your instances separately, and also you'll be able to set different startup settings for games, to run and both monitors.
Though, in your position I would try to find a second machine, for fully separate debugging and use you second monitor to show source code, while game runs on the first one (or vice versa)

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this immediately! I feel ashamed. (+1)

Comment: Do you even need two copies of the sources? Wouldn't two copies of the relevant .csproj files be sufficient (and two sln files)? The csproj files would have the same physical files in them, so if you make a source code change, it will automatically be used by both projects.

Comment: If you don't do copies you'll have problems:
1. With project start settings, which are name your.csproj.user
2. If you copy csproj files and and sln files, you'll have much worse problems with synchonization: consider the case when you want to remove, add, or rename a source file.
I would prefer to give that work to a modern VCS, and don't bother :)